# Web socket on Google Cloud Platform - Network bandwidth is so high

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, socket.io, google-compute-engine

I've developed a web socket application using `socket.io` NodeJS and deployed it in Google Compute Engine. This application is serving more than 300 users at the same time slot always.

The only issue I'm facing here is the network bandwidth cost, really it's getting so higher than usual but I need assistance on improvements in source code or the way of appropriate implementation technique which can help me to reduce this network bandwidth cost.

I really appreciate the support if anyone has come across similar circumstances.

Please refer to the part of my source code.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const moment = require('moment')
const multer = require('multer')
const apkParser = require('node-apk-parser')
const io = require('socket.io')(http)

const expressStatusMonitor = require('express-status-monitor')
app.use(expressStatusMonitor({ websocket: io, port: app.get('port') }))

const session_handler = require('io-session-handler').from(io, { timeout: 0 })

http.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running at 0.0.0.0:3001`))
```

Below is my trial cost report from GCP for 11 days. You can see here the network cost as "Compute Engine Network Internet Standard Tier Egress from Iowa: 124.494 Gibibytes"

> 124.494 GB in 11 days for $10.58

[image: cost report]

Used libraries

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/io-session-handler

Comment: You have not provided any data on what is being consumed and by whom. Review the logfiles to see who is doing what.

Answer (score 2):

**Optimising your egress charges requires an analysis of the amount and direction of it.**

Start using [VPC flow logs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs) which will give you some amount of information, you can analyse VM network logs to give you more information.

Here's a very informative article about [how to utilise VPC Flow Logs](https://blog.doit-intl.com/the-truth-behind-google-cloud-egress-traffic-6e8f57b5c2f8).

You may also find a [gcp networking best pracice](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/networking-cost-optimization-best-practices)s an usefull information.

Also - going through [GCP network pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing) might give you some ideas on how to "direct" your traffic to generate less cost.

Without more details trying to give you some pointers would a pure speculation because amount of traffic in the network may vary greatly depending on many factors.

Comment: VPC Flow Logs are a great tool. For future readers, be aware that the cost is $0.50/GB https://cloud.google.com/vpc/pricing